# Mass post format changer?

Tags: post-formats

Hi I am working on a site that has over 1500 posts. Many of those posts are in the gallery post format, but I need to change them to the "Standard" format to work with the clients current theme.

Is there any way I can automate this? [image]

Answer (score 0):

- Back-up your db
- Add this code to your functions.php file from your theme:

  ```
  $all_posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type'   => 'post',
  ));

  foreach($all_posts as $p)
    set_post_format($p->ID, 'standard');
  ```
- Refresh
- Remove the code

---

Or with a SQL command:

```
UPDATE `term_relationships`
  SET term_taxonomy_id = 'standard_post_format_id'
  WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 'gallery_post_format_id'
```

Change `standard_post_format_id` and `gallery_post_format_id` with the IDs matching post format names from the term_taxonomy/terms tables